# Can a set of 6 sided die, simulate any other die?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

So suppose I only have 6 sided dice, or D6. I want to play an RPG where a D20, or D10 is required. Can I simulate a D20 or D10 or any other sided die, using one or more D6?

Comment: You can simulate a D5 by always rerolling on one result, say $6$.  So you can do a similar thing for D10 or D20, except that you have to have a way to make the results be of equal probability.  One way to do this is to use two dice at a time and treat the results as being base 6, which gives a D36 if you can differentiate the two results, say with different-colored dice.

Comment: Yea you can. Clearly, you can simulate $D_{36}$ via two rolls, so just reroll if the result is above 20.

Comment: Presumably you are hoping for a uniform, independent simulation...

Comment: I’ve provided an answer below.  I conjecture, but do not know, that my technique minimizes the expected number of rolls necessary to obtain a result.  Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer, there is no way to use D$6$ to emulate D$10$ with a guaranteed finite number of rolls.  Suppose you roll $N$ times.  There are $6^N$ possible results.  However, since $6^N$ is not a multiple of $10$, you cannot divide the results into $10$ equal subsets.

Comment: While guaranteed finite rolls is not possible, the finite (and, in practice, little) expected number of rolls is trivially possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re willing to roll the dice as often as necessary to get a result, you can use a D$6$ (or any other die you’d like)  to emulate any die you’d like.  Just think of a roll of the die (minus $1$) as the next digit in a fraction written in base $6$.  There is a probability of $1$ that you’ll get a determinate result after finitely many rolls.

Comment: You write in another comment: "I conjecture, but do not know, that my technique minimizes the expected number of rolls necessary to obtain a result. Does anyone know for sure?" Well, imagine using a d100 to simulate a d99. A very efficient way to do that is to just re-roll if you roll a 100, and otherwise take the result as-is, for an expected number of rolls very close to 1. But if I understand your technique correctly, it will require 2 or more rolls 98% of the time.